# TypeError at /register/ 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I am currently developing a blogging web app and I tried to extend my Django User Framework With a One To One Field, everything is working fine, but when I'm trying to register a new user, it's throwing a TypeError. It is also worth noting that the user is being created and stored (I checked it from the admin page).

It is saying that this statement `profile.user = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)` in my views.py is creating the problem.

my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    CHOICES = (
        ('AB+', 'AB+'),
        ('AB-', 'AB-'),
        ('A+', 'A+'),
        ('A-', 'A-'),
        ('B+', 'B+'),
        ('B-', 'B-'),
        ('O+', 'O+'),
        ('O-', 'O-'),
        )
    bloodgroup = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices= CHOICES)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, ProfileForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)  
            profile.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form, 'profile_form': profile_form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

my signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think two signals you wrote are unnecessary. Also, this line will not work either:

```
profile.user = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Because you are not logged in yet. Without being logged in, you can't get user instance here. But there is no need. Because, you can get the user instance from another form. Like this:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user  
            profile.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Also be sure to remove those two signals.